# CKEditor only loads after onload?

Tags: javascript, performance, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm developing an enhancement extension for a website. I use CKEditor to add a WYSIWYG editor to the forums.

However, I've noticed that CKEditor only loads after every resource (body onload) has loaded (body onload). Most people in the forums use 5MB+ GIFs, so this really affects the load time.

[image]

Since all the javascript files are in the extension, file sizes aren't the problem. I'm not using jQuery either.

Is it possible to alter CKEditor or something so it runs only when the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Why not rewrite the site instead so that the immense, gigantic, massive, gargantuan horrible gifs load after the body onload? Also, how do you initialize cke?

Comment: @Nenotlep The site isn't mine though. The extension inserts ckeditor.js on document load, but ckeditor doesn't insert other files (plugins, dialogs, etc) until body onload

Comment: Do you use `CKEDITOR.replace()` or automatic replacing? Automatic replacing happens on DOM load, `CKEDITOR.replace()` you can run right after elements that will be replaced.

Comment: @Reinmar I tried `CKEDITOR.replace()` and it loaded faster, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Reinmar suggested, I've used `CKEDITOR.replace()` and now I can load it before body onload.

```
CKEDITOR.replace("id");
```